# Android - Security On Saving Data

Tags: android, sqlite, security, sharedpreferences, store

I wanna save a user's score that is retrieved from a server, locally, in order to reduce number of calls to the server.
However if I use SharedPreferences, it could be easily edited by the user. If I use a local database, it could also be changed if user has root access.
So is there any way to safely store data? Should I encode it?
Note that I can't check if local score equals server score, because it may be modified by the app.

Comment: Is it okay for the application to make a call to the server to retrieve the score upon startup, or do you want the score to permanently live on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to enforce security while saving data in either to save it on your server and enforce security there. But, if you want it to be saved on local; then encrypt them and save them.

- For sqlite encryption; https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/
  is great. ([link to project](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher))
- For saving files or blob data https://github.com/facebook/conceal may
  help.
- For saving simple key-value pairs in sharedprefs -
  https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android is useful

It is not good to save sensitive data such as user's personal information and/or passwords in shared preferences or raw sqlite database without encryption.

Comment: I will encypt data, and database will use server data, but server won't use database data. The app will directly modify server values, but show database ones.

Comment: Encryption does not imply data integrity.  The right answer is to MAC (message authentication code) rather than encrypt.  And still, you have just shifted the problem to hiding the key, which is what motivated my question to the original poster above.